# React JS how to have a component moving to next row when window is getting smaller

Tags: css, reactjs

In my product detail page, There are two components - an image gallery on the left and product information on the right. I want the product information component move to next row when the window is getting smaller. I tried difference css styles and fail to make it work. When the window get smaller, the two components still stay on the same row. and make the image gallery too small to display:

Below is my current code,
DetailProdcut.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ProductImages from './ProductImages';
import ProductInfo from './ProductInfo';
import {productItems} from '../Data';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import './DetailProductPage.css';


function DetailProductPage() {

    const { id }=useParams();
    const [details, setDetails]=useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setDetails(productItems.find(item => String(item.id) ===id ))
    
     }, [id]);
        
    return (
        <div className="postPage" style={{width:'100%', padding: '5rem 3rem'}}>

        <div className="detailInfo">
          <div className="detailLeft">
               <ProductImages detail={details} />
           </div>

           <div className="detailRight">
               <ProductInfo  detail={details} />
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  )
}

export default DetailProductPage
```

DetailProduct.css

```
.detailInfo{
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: space-between; */
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  max-width: 1500px;
  background-color: white;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.detailLeft {
  flex:2;
  max-width: 850px;
  height:auto;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 30x;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  
}

.detailRight{
  flex:1;
  width: 40%;
  height:auto;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using @media screen of css, it can solve your issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, but when I use @media (max-width: 50px) {} to the .detailInfo. The whole .detailRight component did move down, no matter the screen is smaller or larger, which means the component does not respond to screen change

Answer (score 1):

Try to use window innerWidth for screen size check.
You can refer below example for more info.
[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/jagretz/pen/VWbwOQ)

```
class WindowWidth extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { 
      height: window.innerHeight, 
      width: window.innerWidth
    };
    this.updateDimensions = this.updateDimensions.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.state.height);
    // Additionally I could have just used an arrow function for the binding `this` to the component...
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions);
  }
  updateDimensions() {
    this.setState({
      height: window.innerHeight, 
      width: window.innerWidth
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <h3>
        Window width: {this.state.width} and height: {this.state.height}
      </h3>
    );
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateDimensions);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<WindowWidth />, document.querySelector(".root"));
```

Comment: Thanks, but It still can not solve my problem.  The elements/components get smaller, and text more to next row using the above code, but what I want is to move the whole product info component/element down to next row, just below the image gallery component when screen get smaller. Maybe I did not apply to code correctly